# Does choosing "suicide" from the pause menu make your team lose a ticket?

Tags: battlefield-3

I've been wondering if I can choose to suicide from the game menu without hurting my team, but too nervous to try it.

Occasionally I'll find myself super far from the action, or regret that I picked the wrong class, and I want to suicide to fix the issue quickly. Am I right to avoid that and play out the life?

Comment: Interesting question. Try it and watch the counter. I wouldn't think it would, but I don't know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suiciding in-game equals dying by getting shot or blown up, so, yes, your team will lose a ticket every time you do that.

My advice: Play along defensively, and switch to another class by picking up a team mate's equipment.

Comment: Ah yes, I always forget I can change classes like that.

Answer (score 6):

It counts as a ticket UNLESS you do it during the pre round countdown. If you suicide to change class at the very beginning of the game you are in the clear.

Comment: not true in case of Conquest.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think this was intended though. If you play Wake island or any map that one team starts with all the flags the tickets are dropping during the damn countdown. This can't be fair or intentional.

Comment: I totally agree that it's not the way it should work.

Comment: See my comment to vartec's answer. He is IN the game. Pre-round time is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

It's bit more complicated than Bora's and Emerica's answers.

If you suicide after the round already started, your team will lose a ticket.

If you suicide during pre-round countdown in Conquest or Assault Conquest, your team will lose a ticket also.

If you suicide during pre-round countdown in Rush, your team will not lose a ticket. During countdown the ticket count set at 0, and it is reset when each section of Rush starts.

Comment: Theoretically, you are right. In his case, though, he wants to get back into action quickly, so he actually IS in game and not in pre-round.